# Need to Prove Result in Stochastic Calculus using Ito's Lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I can't figure out where :
\begin{align}
\delta^2\,dt\\
\end{align}

comes from.

Consider the process
$$
d\sqrt{v} = = (\alpha - \beta\sqrt{v})\,dt + \delta \,dW
$$
Here $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\delta$ are constants. Using Ito's Lemma show that 
$$
dv = (\delta^2 + 2\alpha\sqrt{v} - 2\beta v)\,dt + 2\delta\sqrt{v}\,dW
$$

Notice that $v = f(\sqrt{v})$ for $f(x)=x^2$. We have $f'(x)=2x$ and $f''(x)=2$.

Ito's lemma yields:
$$
dv = f'(\sqrt{v})\,d\sqrt{v} + \frac{1}{2}f''(\sqrt{v})\,d\langle\sqrt{v}\rangle.
$$

Hence
\begin{align}
dv &= 2\sqrt{v}\times\left((\alpha-\beta\sqrt{v})\,dt + \delta \,dW\right) + \frac{1}{2}\times 2\times\delta^2\,dt\\
&=(\delta^2 + 2\alpha\sqrt{v} - 2\beta v)\,dt + 2\delta \sqrt{v}\, dW.
\end{align}

Comment: The derivation you've provided here looks okay.  What part are you confused about?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathrm dX_t=a_t\mathrm dW_t+b_t\mathrm dt$ then $\mathrm d\langle X\rangle_t=a_t^2\mathrm dt$. Here $a_t=\delta$, hence the $\delta^2\mathrm dt$ term.